# Python CSV Processing: Existing Users Not Retained in Output File When Adding New Users

Tags: python, csv, automation

When adding new users to a CSV file using a Python script, the previously added users are not retained in the output file. The script reads existing users from an output CSV file, processes new users from an input CSV file, and writes both existing and new users to the output CSV file. However, only the new users are being written to the output file, and the existing users are not retained. Below is the snippet of my code.

```
import csv
import secrets
import subprocess
from pathlib import Path

# Sets the path to the data directory
data_dir = Path("/home/shayan/Desktop/Python Script/Script_1/data")

# Reading the existing users from the output file
existing_users = set()
try:
    with open(data_dir / "users_out.csv", "r") as file_output:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_output)
        for user in reader:
            existing_users.add(user["username"])
except FileNotFoundError:
    pass  # Ignores if the file does not exist yet

# Reading the input file and creating output file
with open(data_dir / "users_in.csv", "r") as file_input, open(data_dir / "users_out.csv", "a") as file_output:
    fieldnames = ["username", "password", "real_name"]
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    # Processes new users from the input file
    reader = csv.DictReader(file_input)
    for user in reader:
        if "username" in user and user["username"] not in existing_users:
            # Generating a random 16-character password
            user["password"] = secrets.token_hex(8)

            # Runing useradd command to create user account
            useradd_cmd = ["/sbin/useradd",
                           "-c", user["real_name"],
                           "-m",
                           "-G", "users",
                           "-p", user["password"],
                           user["username"]]
            try:
                subprocess.run(useradd_cmd, check=True)
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
                # If User already exists, print a message and continue to the next user
                print(f"User '{user['username']}' already exists. Skipping...")
                continue

            # Writing the new user record with password to output file
            writer.writerow(user)

    print("Finished processing users.")
```

The script should retain existing users in the output file while adding new users from the input file.

Comment: this requires a [mcve] with actual input

Comment: Cannot reproduce. I changed to read current directory and didn't actually run the add command for test. These are things you could do in your question so we don't have to modify the script ourselves. There is one bug when users_out.csv doesn't exist - you don't add a header to the file - but that would have a different error. Otherwise, using several different in files, it all worked.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Since I am new here, this was my first question, and I wasn't sure about the formatting and details required in the question. I will make sure to include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example in future questions, including the actual input files and any relevant code snippets needed to reproduce the issue. I will also clarify any changes made to the script and ensure that I handle missing CSV headers properly. Thank you for your guidance.

Comment: You forgot to write the headers to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mocked up existing and new CSVs, to try and make the naming and expectations clearer.  The existing CSV looks like:

```
| username | password | real_name |
|----------|----------|-----------|
| alicec   | passwd1  | Alice     |
| bobbyt   | passwd2  | Bobby     |
| charliem | passwd3  | Charlie   |
```

and the new CSV looks like:

```
| username | password | real_name |
|----------|----------|-----------|
| alicec   | passwd1  | Alice     |
| charliem | passwd3  | Charlie   |
| darylj   | passwd4  | Daryl     |
| erink    | passwd5  | Erin      |
```

So, new duplicates Alice and Charlie, and adds Daryl and Erin.

I distilled your program down to:

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

data_dir = Path(".")
out_csv = data_dir / "existing.csv"
in_csv = data_dir / "new.csv"

existing_users = set()
with open(out_csv) as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        existing_users.add(row["username"])

f_out = open(out_csv, "a")
writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=["username", "password", "real_name"])

f_in = open(in_csv)
reader = csv.DictReader(f_in)
for row in reader:
    if "username" in row and row["username"] not in existing_users:
        # ...cmd stuff...
        writer.writerow(row)
```

and it worked.  The existing CSV (`out_csv`) now looks like:

```
| username | password | real_name |
|----------|----------|-----------|
| alicec   | passwd1  | Alice     |
| bobbyt   | passwd2  | Bobby     |
| charliem | passwd3  | Charlie   |
| darylj   | passwd4  | Daryl     |
| erink    | passwd5  | Erin      |
```

I don't know why it doesn't work for you... I didn't change any logic, and I'm pretty sure even though I changed the names, I kept the semantics/flow the same.

Also, `if 'username' in row ...` probably isn't checking what you intended: this only checks if the key exists in the dict, and the only way for a key **not to exist** in a DictReader dict is if the entire column didn't exist in the CSV being read. If you meant to check if the username value for that row was empty or not, you'd need something like, `if row['username'].strip() != '' ...`.

Even so, I recommend a different approach: don't try to append to (overwrite) an existing file; instead, create a new *final* CSV, and when you're satisfied with the results replace the original (existing CSV).  Also, you only need to read the original once.

```py
import csv

existing_csv = "existing.csv"
new_csv = "new.csv"
final_csv = "output-final.csv"

# Read existing rows directly into a list so we can iterate it repeatedly,
# in multiple steps
f_in = open(existing_csv, newline="")
existing_rows = list(csv.DictReader(f_in))
existing_usernames = set([x["username"] for x in existing_rows])


# Set up new rows and final writer
f_out = open(final_csv, "w", newline="")
writer = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=existing_rows[0])

f_in = open(new_csv, newline="")
new_rows = list(csv.DictReader(f_in))


# Start by writing all existing rows to final
for row in existing_rows:
    writer.writerow(row)

# Now, add in new rows (if not an existing user)
for row in new_rows:
    if row["username"] in existing_usernames:
        continue

    # do cmd stuff

    writer.writerow(row)
```

My final CSV looks like:

```
| alicec   | passwd1 | Alice   |
|----------|---------|---------|
| bobbyt   | passwd2 | Bobby   |
| charliem | passwd3 | Charlie |
| darylj   | passwd4 | Daryl   |
| erink    | passwd5 | Erin    |
```

For a simple script that runs, opens the files, then exits, you don't need to close the files explicitly (the Python runtime handles that for you); you can add that back in if you like.

Comment: Thank you for the solution! It worked perfectly and resolved my issue, which was becoming quite a headache. Your assistance was incredibly helpful, and I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to write out the header. Here is the fix:

```py
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
```

## Explanation

Since you did not write the header, the first line of `users_out.csv` might look like this:

```
dstirland0,766bc0bd11cbee78,Dory Stirland
```

And that line will be used as header next time you read the file. That means the line

```py
            existing_users.add(user["username"])
```

will generage a `KeyError` because `username` is not part of the header.